# VirtualBox installation fails on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, gcc, ubuntu-22.04

I'm trying to install VirtualBox on Ubuntu 22.04.

I downloaded the right [.deb](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/7.0.12/virtualbox-7.0_7.0.12-159484%7EUbuntu%7Ejammy_amd64.deb) from the official site and installed with `sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-7.0_7.0.12-159484\~Ubuntu\~jammy_amd64.deb` which gave this:

```
Wybieranie wcześniej niewybranego pakietu virtualbox-7.0.
(Odczytywanie bazy danych ... 357166 plików i katalogów obecnie zainstalowanych.)
Przygotowywanie do rozpakowania pakietu virtualbox-7.0_7.0.12-159484~Ubuntu~jammy_amd64.deb ...
Rozpakowywanie pakietu virtualbox-7.0 (7.0.12-159484~Ubuntu~jammy) ...
Konfigurowanie pakietu virtualbox-7.0 (7.0.12-159484~Ubuntu~jammy) ...
Dodawanie grupy "vboxusers" (GID 141)...
Gotowe.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vbox-setup.log to find out what went wrong.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.  If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign the
kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load
them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.
Przetwarzanie wyzwalaczy pakietu mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1)...
Przetwarzanie wyzwalaczy pakietu gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3)...
Przetwarzanie wyzwalaczy pakietu desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3)...
Przetwarzanie wyzwalaczy pakietu hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2)...
Przetwarzanie wyzwalaczy pakietu shared-mime-info (2.1-2)...
```

The same happens for `sudo apt install virtualbox`.

It's in polish, but the relevant part is that `vboxdrv.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vbox-setup.log to find out what went wrong`. The file says:

```
Building the main VirtualBox module.
Error building the module:
make V=1 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG= CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_ALL= -C /lib/modules/6.4.10-060410-generic/build M=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 -j16 modules
make[1]: uwaga: -j16 wymuszone w podzadaniu: wyłączanie trybu serwera zadań.
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-1ubuntu1) 13.2.0
  You are using:           
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=/tmp/vbox.0 need-builtin=1 need-modorder=1 
# cmd_mod /tmp/vbox.0/vboxdrv.mod
  printf '%s
'   linux/SUPDrv-linux.o SUPDrv.o SUPDrvGip.o SUPDrvSem.o SUPDrvTracer.o SUPLibAll.o common/string/strformatrt.o combined-agnostic1.o combined-agnostic2.o combined-os-specific.o | awk '!x[$0]++ { print("/tmp/vbox.0/"$0) }' > /tmp/vbox.0/vboxdrv.mod
# CC [M]  /tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o
  gcc-13 -Wp,-MMD,/tmp/vbox.0/linux/.SUPDrv-linux.o.d -nostdinc -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/compiler-version.h -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Werror=strict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fshort-wchar -fno-PIE -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=return-type -Wno-format-security -funsigned-char -std=gnu11 -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -mno-80387 -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mfunction-return=thunk-extern -fno-jump-tables -mharden-sls=all -fpatchable-function-entry=16,16 -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-main -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -ftrivial-auto-var-init=zero -fzero-call-used-regs=used-gpr -pg -mrecord-mcount -falign-functions=16 -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wvla -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-alloc-size-larger-than -Wimplicit-fallthrough=5 -fno-strict-overflow -fno-stack-check -fconserve-stack -Werror=date-time -g -gdwarf-5 -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-pie -Wno-declaration-after-statement -I./include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_WITHOUT_PRAGMA_ONCE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DSUPDRV_WITH_RELEASE_LOGGER -DVBOX_WITHOUT_EFLAGS_AC_SET_IN_VBOXDRV -DIPRT_WITHOUT_EFLAGS_AC_PRESERVING -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS -DCONFIG_VBOXDRV_AS_MISC -DRT_ARCH_AMD64  -fsanitize=bounds -fsanitize=shift -fsanitize=bool -fsanitize=enum  -DMODULE  -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"SUPDrv_linux"' -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"vboxdrv"' -D__KBUILD_MODNAME=kmod_vboxdrv -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o /tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c   ; ./tools/objtool/objtool --hacks=jump_label --hacks=noinstr --hacks=skylake --retpoline --rethunk --sls --stackval --static-call --uaccess --prefix=16   --module /tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o
/bin/sh: 1: gcc-13: not found
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:252: /tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o] Błąd 127
make[1]: *** [Makefile:2038: /tmp/vbox.0] Błąd 2
make: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/Makefile-footer.gmk:133: vboxdrv] Błąd 2
```

which clearly states that `gcc-13: not found`. But `sudo apt install gcc-13` gives

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gcc-13
```

The same for `gcc13`.

How can I install `gcc-13`? Or am I doing something wrong while installing VirtualBox?

Comment: First, I don't use Ubuntu, but I would have thought you would need to install `gcc13`, not `gcc-13`. Secondly, to install the modules, either disable secure boot, or create a signing certificate, load it into EFI DB, sign the modules & then load them. Your cert will have to have the code signing OID enabled. Use `xca`, it simplifies things greatly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason why you prefer to install VirtualBox manually and not using the `apt`?

#### Install VirtualBox from Ubuntu repositories:

```
sudo apt install virtualbox
```

#### Install gcc-13 on Ubuntu 22.04:

Installing gcc-13 on Ubuntu 22.04 can be a bit more tricky, because the package is not part of 22.04. So, you will have to use `ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test` repo, or build the package by yourself.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gcc-13
```

Comment: I was missing that repo. Installing `gcc-13` and enabling VT-x allowed VirtualBox to work.